# Facebook throws error without code

Tags: javascript, facebook

Facebook throws me unknown error:

> "Error is acquired. Please try again later."

There is no any error in Firefox console.

My JavaScript source is:

```
(function () {
    function requestCallback(response) {
        var message = document.getElementById("success_message");
        if (message) {
            if (typeof response.error_code != 'undefined') {
                message.innerHTML = 'Wrong';
            } else {
                message.innerHTML = 'Success';
            }
        }
    }

    var vkInvite = function () {
        if (typeof FB == 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(vkInvite, 100);
        } else {
            console.log("Try to use facebook... FB.init");
            FB._initialized = false;
            FB.init({
                appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                frictionlessRequests: true
            });
            (function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
                console.log("Try to use facebook... FB.ui");
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'apprequests',
                    message: 'Message.'
                }, requestCallback);
            })();
        }
    }();
})();
```

How to diagnose the output of Facebook framework?

Comment: Trying to check whether the SDK is initialized via a timer loop is a bad idea. Why don’t you use the fbAsyncInit event as described in the docs to execute your code you want to run once it is done initializing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any error.
Access to dialogue window has been changed by Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Requests are only available for games on Facebook.com or iOS and Android apps. Accepting a request from a game will direct the person to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request. For native mobile apps, accepting the request will direct the person to the app on their device if installed or to the appropriate location (Apple App Store or Google Play) to download the app otherwise.